# python - remove text of string

Tags: python, string

I have a string that looks like this

```
name = '1/23/20151'
```

And now I want to remove just the trailing 1, at the end of 2015. So that it becomes

```
1/23/2015
```

So i tried this

```
sep = '2015'
name = name.split(sep, 1)[0]
```

but this removes the 2015 also, I want the 2015 to stay, how could I do this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

Sorry I didn't fully explain the problem I have two strings the one previously mentioned and a noraml date `'1/22/2015'` and I loop through and only want to remove this extra character if it is there which is why `name = name[:-1]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
name = name.rstrip('1')
```

will only remove trailing '1'

```
name = '1/23/20151'
name = name.rstrip('1') # 1/23/2015
'1/23/2015'.rstrip('1') # 1/23/2015
```

Comment: Note: this will also strip trailing 1's for years ending in 1, e.g. `2011` becomes `20`, which I don't think is the desired outcome.

Comment: See my updated solution.  I think this would accomplish what he is intending without any added side effects

Answer (score 2):

just do this

```
name = name[:-1]
```

That should do it.

If you only want to remove the fifth digit after the year, I'd do this:

```
name = name.split('/')
name = '/'.join([name[0],name[1],name[2][:4]])
```

Comment: will the trailing digit always be a one?

Answer (score 1):

List slicing can easily accomplish this:

```
>>> name[:-1]
>>> '1/23/2015'
```